# Change header layout in moderncv

Tags: titles, moderncv

I am creating a CV with the moderncv classic style. My header looks so far like this:

[image]:

I would like to achieve that

1. the name and title are not aligned at the lower, but at the upper end of the box.
2. the name is "overlapping" with the address box, because I have to make the name smaller at the moment to avoid a line break.

I guess that I have to change *moderncvstyleclassic.sty*. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the syntax so I cannot figure out what to change.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

\moderncvstyle{classic}            
\moderncvcolor{grey}         
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{25}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\firstname{Dr. Marcus}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{Biochemist}           
\address{Street abc}{D-80331 Munich}  
\mobile{+49 xxx / xx xx xx xx}               
\email{marcus.surname@dummy.com}         

\photo[90pt][0.4pt]{dummy}                      
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not compile :-( The `\title{...} and its multiple `\\` generate errors

Comment: There's an easy way, and a hard way. The easy way could be hackish, but the hard way would mean a complete copy-and-paste of `\makecvtitle` to reconfigure it to suit your needs (since [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) isn't adjustable in that way). For your first problem, you can use `\familyname{\rlap{Surname that is long}}`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks you. I've eliminated the multiple '\\' again. They were in there accidentally from a test that I've made before posting.

Comment: If you replace them by `\newline`, you can at least shift the name and title to the top, but is not really nice ;-)

Comment: @Werner: Thank you! That may not be the "correct" way to do it, but gives me what I want for the moment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, that is what I will probably do as a "quick and dirty" solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify `\makecvtitle` (however unwieldy):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

\moderncvstyle{classic}            
\moderncvcolor{grey}         
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{25}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\makecvtitlepicturebox][t]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{Dr. Marcus}
\familyname{\rlap{Surname that is long}}
\title{Biochemist}
\address{Street abc}{D-80331 Munich}  
\mobile{+49 xxx / xx xx xx xx}               
\email{marcus.surname@dummy.com}         

\photo[90pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}                      
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

It's all about adjusting the boxes that make up the header. It's easiest to still supply your `\familyname` with an additional `\rlap`. The adjustment for the name uses some detail about [`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/minipage/info) - specifically specifying a fixed height.